# How to get pass and fail count using extent Report in code?

Tags: automation, automated-tests, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I am using extent report for reporting purpose. I want to send a message to team with the pass and fail test count.

### Example:

[test_environment] test_suite_name: "num_tests_passed /num_total_tests" | report_link

Please help.

Comment: That's a feature of the professional version.

Comment: @BillHileman Ah! If that's true, that'd be surprising for me, because simple statistical numbers like num_tests_passed, num_tests_failed, num_total_tests are a basic feature of any reporting library/framework.

Comment: I'm not saying it can't be done, but specifically the e-mail part is listed as a feature of the professional version only.  e-mailing is not all that complicated either, but I found nothing on their web site in a quick scan to determine how to get the information this poster wants to e-mail.  It can probably be done, unless they specifically prevent access to entice the purchase of the pro version.

Answer (score 1):

You can count them in the **TestListener** class. For example:

```
int all_testCases=0;
.
.
.
.
public synchronized void onTestStart(ITestResult iTestResult) {
.
.
.
all_testCases= all_testCases + 1; 
}
```

- **onTestStart** you can count the total number of tests
- **onTestFailure** you can count the total number of tests that failed
- **onTestSuccess**  you can count the total number of tests that passed
- **onTestSkipped** you can count the total number of tests that skipped

Or you can count them in @AfterMethod, e.g

```
public void tearDownDriver(ITestResult result) {
    driver.quit();
    try {
        if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {
            success_tests++;
        } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
            fail_tests++;
        } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP) {
            skip_tests++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then you can send an email with the details you need.